# Workflow Error Occurred in SharePoint site

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, settings, workflow

I have added a workflow to list using three-state template. It was working before, but for some reason it had stopped working and does not create a task when initiated.

Status:   Error Occurred

I have tried deleting and creating new workflow, this error remained. I have tried to migrate into another list but workflow error still happening.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010? Can you provide more details about the workflow?